# Extract key-value pairs as a tuple from nested json with python

Tags: python, json

I want to extract all key-value pairs from JSON file, I loaded it as a Python dictionary.
I created this function below that stores all values. However, I am struggling to put them inside a list to store them like that. Any support is very appreciated.

```
json_example = {'name': 'TheDude',
 'age': '19',
 'hobbies': {
         'love': 'eating',
         'hate': 'reading',
         'like': [
                 {'outdoor': {
                         'teamsport': 'soccer',
                        }
                 }
                 ]
        }
  }


# My code - Extract values

def extract_values(dct, lst=[]):
    if not isinstance(dct, (list, dict)):
        lst.append(dct)
    elif isinstance(dct, list):
        for i in dct:
            extract_values(i, lst)
    elif isinstance(dct, dict):
        for v in dct.values():
            extract_values(v, lst)
    return lst

# Extract keys

def matt_keys(dct):
    if not isinstance(dct, (list, dict)):
        return ['']
    if isinstance(dct, list):
        return [dk for i in dct for dk in matt_keys(i)]
    return [k+('_'+dk if dk else '') for k, v in dct.items() for dk in matt_keys(v)]
```

Current output:

```
['TheDude', '19', 'eating'...]
```

Desired output:

```
[('name': 'TheDude'), ('age', '19'), ..., ('hobbies_love', 'eating'), ... , ('hobbies_like_outdoor_teamsport', 'soccer')]
```

Also if there is a more efficient or cleaner way to extract this, then it would be great.

Comment: What's the point of storing them in a list?

Comment: are you interested in the examples in the `like ` section ?

Comment: yes, i need everything including lists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Issues**:
Your recursive function currently does not pass the key as part of the function call. Also, you will need to deal with nesting when trying to create the key.

**Hints**: We can assemble a list of all the keys that lead to a particular value (e.g. `['hobbies', 'love']`) and then join the keys into a single string (e.g. `hobbies_love`).

**Solution**: Here is your code with the changes implemented:

```
def extract_values(dct, lst=[], keys=[]):
    if not isinstance(dct, (list, dict)):
        lst.append(('_'.join(keys), dct))
    elif isinstance(dct, list):
        for i in dct:
            extract_values(i, lst, keys)
    elif isinstance(dct, dict):
        for k, v in dct.items():
            keys.append(k)
            extract_values(v, lst, keys)
            keys.remove(k)
    return lst


x = extract_values(json_example)
print(x)
```

**Output**: The above code will produce the following desired output:

```
[('name', 'TheDude'), ('age', '19'), ('hobbies_love', 'eating'), ('hobbies_hate', 'reading'), ('hobbies_like_outdoor_teamsport', 'soccer')]
```

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to get key-value pairs as well. I updated the question.

Comment: No problem. I have updated the solution so that it also returns the keys where each key gives the full nesting path.

Comment: Can you explain why you use remove?

Comment: Once a dictionary has been (recursively) processed, the key is no longer required. If it is not removed, then the next item we process will add to the existing keys. E.g. we set `keys` to `'name'`, process its value and then remove `'name'` before moving on to `'age'`. If we don't then we will end up with `keys` set to `['name', 'age']`.

Answer (score 0):

well, here'sa different approach for your desired solution (used recursivity):

```
def extract_values(json_dict):
    result = []
    for key , value in json_dict.items():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            result += [
                (f'{key}_{val[0]}', val[1]) for val in extract_values(value)
                ]
        elif isinstance(value, str):
            result.append((key, value))
        elif isinstance(value, list):
            result += [
                (f'{key}_{val[0]}', val[1]) for i in range(len(value)) 
                for val in extract_values(value[i])
                ]
        else:
            continue 

    return result
```

to test ..

```
# testing:
json_example = {'name': 'TheDude',
 'age': '19',
 'hobbies': {
         'love': 'eating',
         'hate': 'reading',
         'like': [
                 {'outdoor': {
                         'teamsport': 'soccer',
                        }
                 }
                 ]
        }
  }

print(extract_values(json_example))
```

output:

```
[('name', 'TheDude'), ('age', '19'), ('hobbies_love', 'eating'), ('hobbies_hate', 'reading'), ('hobbies_like_outdoor_teamsport', 'soccer')]
```

Comment: Thanks! I want to add the like example. How would you add it?

Comment: it depends how you want it to be, can you give an example ? (either as a new param on the set or incorporated in the string like with the hobbies types) ?

Comment: Like this: ('hobbies_like_outdoor_teamsport', 'soccer')

Comment: @matt.aurelio I updated the solution to match your desired output, check it out !

Answer (score 0):

When you use `json.load` or `json.loads` to get your Python object from the JSON file/string, you can pass in an object hook that completely simplifies what you are trying to do with the Python object. Read the JSON module docs for more info.

```py
from json import load, loads
key_value_pairs = list()
object_hook = lambda obj: key_value_pairs.extend(obj.items())

# if you’re reading a json file
_ = load(open("myfile.json"), object_hook=object_hook)

# if you’re reading a json string
_ = loads(myjsonstr, object_hook=object_hook)

# at this point, `key_value_pairs` will be a
# flat list of every kv-pair
```

Answer (score -2):

Here's my try with the `yield` keyword which avoid the list as argument:

```py
json_example = {'name': 'TheDude',
 'age': '19',
 'hobbies': {
         'love': 'eating',
         'hate': 'reading',
         'like': [
                 {'outdoor': {
                         'teamsport': 'soccer',
                        }
                 }
                 ]
        }
  }


def extract_values(dct, prefix=""):
    if isinstance(dct, str):
        yield prefix, dct
    else:
        try:
            for key, one_value in dct.items():
                if prefix:
                    new_prefix = "_".join([prefix, key])
                else:
                    new_prefix = key
                yield from extract_values(one_value, prefix=new_prefix)
        except AttributeError:
            for one_value in dct:
                yield from extract_values(one_value, prefix=prefix)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print([one_value for one_value in extract_values(json_example)])
```

it prints:

```
[('name', 'TheDude'), ('age', '19'), ('hobbies_love', 'eating'), ('hobbies_hate', 'reading'), ('hobbies_like_outdoor_teamsport', 'soccer')]
```

Comment: the 'name_age...' shouldn t be present in each key i think .. , it is repeated unnecessarely

Comment: Sorry for this, I corrected.

Comment: np! dont forget to correct the output too :)